# View or function 'Dept20' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why do I get View or function 'Dept20' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables?

```
create view Dept20
as select j.kojab as employe_id ,p.nama as employee ,j.gapok
from jabatan j, pegawai p
where j.kojab = p.Kojab
and j.kojab = 4
```

When I want to delete

```
delete from Dept20
where employee = 'rojib2'
```

I get the error:

> Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> View or function 'Dept20' is not updatable because the modification
>   affects multiple base tables.

I need help...

Comment: 2 thing, join using INNER JOIN not syntax you use + WHERE, second if you want to update this you need INSTEAD OF trigger

Comment: You can't delete from the view because a base table may match several view rows.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are running into (by error) is called [Updatable View](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29#Read-only_vs._updatable_views). Basically, the database server is not able to figure out by itself what should be deleted because the reverse mapping from the view to the involved base tables is ambigious. As has been noted in the comments you could look into defining an INSTEAD OF TRIGGER on the view.